# How to revert to local changes in github folder?

Tags: git

I have been working all the days in a latex file in a local folder of github repository. I saved the file locally many times and I forgot to commit it.

I then discarded all the local modifications with the command to restore another file while I forgot to commit my changes.

```
git reset --hard
git pull
```

And then I did the commit while thinking. Is it possible to restore the files I was saving locally?

Comment: which editor do you use? Some make automatic backups.

Comment: I am using texmaker

Comment: Not with git, unfortunately. Git will only save committed or stashed changes. Your text editor might have a history, but I must warn you that most editors do not preserve a history of files after they have been closed. `reset --hard` is dangerous because it will erase local files. Most other git commands will save you if you have local changes. I've done this to myself a couple times... very frustrating. If you find yourself using that command frequently, you might want to invest in a different workflow that allows you to avoid it.

Comment: @emax Check your texmaker preferences if the backup is enabled. If yes a copy of the documents are saved with the .bak extension

Comment: I did not have this option :-(. Thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 1):

Not with git, unfortunately. Git will only save changes that were committed or stashed.

Your text editor might have a history, but very few text editors keep backups of files after they have been closed.

`git reset --hard` is dangerous because it will erase local file changes, even changes that have been "staged", without warning or recourse. Most other git commands will save you if you have local changes by warning you and cancelling the command. I've done this to myself a couple times... very frustrating.

If you find yourself using `reset --hard` frequently, you might want to invest in a different workflow that allows you to avoid it. You could use `git stash -u` instead, for example, which will clear your local changes but also preserve those changes in a "stash" that you can retrieve later if you realize you needed some of those changes. (The `-u` will also preserve "new" files in the stash while also clearing them so you can run a `git pull` without conflicts.)

See [Git Tools - Stashing and Cleaning](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Stashing-and-Cleaning) for more information about stashing changes, including how to get those changes back and how to clean your stashes later on.